# Are there sites where I can sell an Italian train ticket?

Tags: trains, tickets, italy

I purchased a train ticket from Napoli to Milano for July 21st, but later found out that I have leave earlier. The ticket turned out to be non-refundable, so I had to purchase another ticket. Are there groups or forums where I can try to sell this ticket for a portion of the cost, so I don't lose the whole amount?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. When you purchased your ticket, you agreed to  [Trenitalia's conditions of carriage](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/allegati/trenitalia_eng/Conditions_transportation.pdf); tickets designated "nominative" are non-transferable, so if you sell such a ticket to another person, they may not be able to use it. I would think non-refundable tickets are also non-transferable in most if not all cases, because price discrimination would break down, but I am not an expert in the customer service operations of Italian railways.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because, as @choster notes in comment, it's not legal to sell such tickets, so any response would disregard TSE standards.